# Eclipse Neon Does not have Consolas Font

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to find best and the most agreeable font for coding. Needless to say I found consolas which is a visual pleasure. The default font of Eclipse for text editor is hideous. Unfortunately Consolas is not one of the available font under Eclipse > System Preferences > Text Editors.

Is there a way to add Consolas font to eclipse and use it? I was hoping that eclipse is somewhat as smart as MS Word.

Comment: Eclipse does not ship any fonts, it just shows what is available on your OS. Follow whatever the procedures are for installing fonts on your OS.

Comment: @greg-449 Got it! Thanks a bunch!